# Cutting a "channel" halfway into a shape?

Tags: modeling

What I mean:

[image]

How can cut this groove?

The "channel" doesn't go all the way through, probably only half way or so (Using a picture to build my model so I can't tell for sure). It's suppose to be a height adjuster like you would find on a lawnmower for the height of the blades. was wondering if I could use the boolean modifier but I didn't know if one shape has to go all the way through the other shape for the modifier to work properly.

What do you's think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an object with the shape and depth of your cut.

[image]

And use a [Boolean Modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html?highlight=boolean#boolean-modifier) to cut the shape of that object on to the other.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[knife project](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html?highlight=knife#knife-project)**.

By hiding the faces you don't want to cut, you can control which faces get cut with the shape and which are left uncut.

Example:

With the shape object selected,  Shift-Select the object you want to cut and enter edit mode:

[image]

Select the bottom faces (the ones you want to preserve with no cuts) and Hide them (<kbd>H</kbd>)

[image]

Then in top orthogonal view press the <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> and type **Knife Project**. Enable Cut Through** and then unhide the hidden faces (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: After you knife project you can then select the inner faces and transform them along the normal (alt+s by default I think) if you want an inset rather than a hole all the way through.